# ImportError: cannot import name sslhandling

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, cassandra

I've got this while working with Cassandra https://github.com/marionleborgne/cloudbrain/wiki/1.-Setup

```
~/Downloads/cloudbrain/cloudbrain/datastore$ cqlsh -f /home/user/Downloads/cloudbrain/cloudbrain/datastore/cassandra_schema.cql
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 157, in <module>
    from cqlshlib import cql3handling, cqlhandling, pylexotron, sslhandling, copy
ImportError: cannot import name sslhandling
```

Answer (score 1):

Such error may occur when you have installed Cassandra using installator and it haven't installed required python libs. Download tar.gz archive from [cassandra.apache.org/download/](http://cassandra.apache.org/download/), extract it, go to pylib folder in it and run command in terminal

```
python setup.py install --user
```

It is possible that you'll need to reboot your system after that.

Comment: i also have the issue like this.  ImportError: cannot import name cqlshhandling